# Linear transformation

Tags: linear-transformations

Vectors on the planar which maps the origin to the origin, and every other vector to one of the vectors $(1,1) , (2,2), (3,3).$  Is it a linear transformation?

The answer is no because the image is not subspace, but i didn't understand the explanation.  Why is it not enough to check $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$ and $f(cx) = cf(x)$ for the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image of *any* linear map must be a vector space. But you have only four points.

> Why is it not enough to check $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ and $f(cx)=cf(x)f(cx)=cf(x)$ for the problem?

It is enough. But it is just an overkill:
>
Suppose $x\neq0$, then  $$f(x)\in\{(0,0),(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)\}=:S.$$ But $f(2016 x)\not\in S$.

Answer (score 2):

It WOULD be enough to check that. But lacking the actual formula for the transformation, you can't compute $f(x+y)$ to compare it to $f(x)$ and $f(y)$.

On the other hand, you can say that for some vector $v$, we must have $f(v) = (a,a)$ for $a = 1, 2,$ or $3$ (by the hypotheses).

You can then use the rules you like to "If $f$ were linear, then $f(10v) = 10(a,a) = (10a, 10a)$. But for $a = 1, 2, 3$, $10a$ is \emph{not} one of $1,2, 3$ Hence the map cannot be linear."